# how i can count the element who have the class "goo"

Tags: jquery, html

i want to check how much element have class "goo".

are i can check for specific element or all using jQuery. show me how i can do this task in jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706106/count-elements-with-jquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There a [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property to see how many elements a jQuery object references, so just combine that with a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), like this:

```
var count = $(".goo").length;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var amountOfGoo = $('.goo').length;
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `$(".goo").length`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.length` property. So something like `var total = $('.goo').length;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

$(".goo").length