# Count elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to count how many elements on the page with a particular class?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

```
$('.someclass').length
```

<strike>You could also use:</strike>

```
$('.someclass').size()
```

`.size()` is now [removed](http://api.jquery.com/size/) as of jQuery 3.0.

Comment: Am not locating it, but I read on Meta recently *"How do you upvote?"*, and there was a Jeff Atwood quote *"Whenever I research for an issue and find the Answer."* My exact situation.

Comment: Notice that `.size()` method is Deprecated.

Comment: with version 3.1.1, length returns undefined

Comment: @GiovanniBitliner: You sure about that?  https://jsfiddle.net/gwj3v3ca/  I'd be pretty surprised if jQuery made a change in which the jQuery selector no longer returned an array.  That would be a *very* breaking change.

Comment: This seems to count the length of the characters in an element, not the number of elements that have that class.

Comment: @TylerLazenby: You sure about that?  https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/154885/  Do you have an example to demonstrate your claim?

Comment: Yup, I have a question that shows the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907661/mischievous-class-length-result

And the website this is happening on
http://madewithloveandsarcasm.com

Comment: @TylerLazenby: The code in your question isn't using jQuery.  You're just getting the length of a string literal.

Comment: If the element exists: ("#id").length > 0

Answer (score 28):

```
var count_elements = $('.class').length;
```

From: http://api.jquery.com/size/

> The .size() method is functionally
>   equivalent to the .length property;
>   however, the .length property is
>   preferred because it does not have the
>   overhead of a function call.

Please see:

http://api.jquery.com/size/

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 9):

I believe this works:

```
$(".MyClass").length
```

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
var count_element = $('.element').length
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.class').length
```

This one does not work for me. I'd rather use this:

```
$('.class').children().length
```

I don't really know the reason why, but the second one works only for me. Somewhy, either size doesn't work.

Comment: Same for me. I was testing in a React web app I had developed. I didn't install jQuery, so it must be available from one of the dependencies. I was searching for `$("tr")` and I suspect that, in some cases, it returns the first element instead of all of the matched ones.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
var num = 0;

$('.className').each(function(){
    num++;
});
```

Comment: "The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone"

Answer (score 2):

use the `.size()` method or `.length` attribute

Comment: .size() is deprecated