# How to find the number of Divs with a certain Class JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there any way to find the number of DIV's displayed in the browser with class=.class?

Something like this:

```
$('.class').Numberofobjects();
```

*Obviously Numberofobjects is made up.

Thanks!

Taylor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count elements with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706106/count-elements-with-jquery)

Answer (score 7):

You want the `length` property (and make sure to constrain the tag type):

```
$('div.class').length
```

Answer (score 2):

.length will give you the list of classes that match

```
$('.class').length
```

api here

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert($("div.a").length);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Click" />
    <div class="a">
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="a">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
    </div>
</body>
```