# how can i check how many '.classname' items are?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706106/count-elements-with-jquery)

hi there,

i was considering, using jquery,

```
var n = 0;
$('.className').each(function(){
     n = n+1;
});
```

Any better solution in mind?

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length) property:

```
$('.className').length
```

Answer (score 5):

`$('.className')` is an array, so you can use `.length`.

```
$('.className').length
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) or [.size](http://api.jquery.com/size/) properties:

```
$('.className').length

$('.className').size()
```