# How to limit number of divs on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code that loops through and adds 5 divs ('content-section') every time a button is clicked. How would I go about to check how many content-sections are there and skip the loop once 20 content-sections have been appended to the page?

HTML:

```
<div class="content-section news-preview clearfix">
    <div class="title">Title of News Article</div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="images/news_sample208x135.jpg" width="208" height="135"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Dui luctus lectus eget libero volupat, a tempor velit malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mattis egestas lorem a sodales.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="article-link">http://www.lintothenewsarticle.com/news/article/title-of-news-article</a>
</div><!-- /content-section -->
```

jQuery:

```
var maxNewsCards = 20;

$('.show-more').click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        // var contentNews = $('div.content-section:last').prop('outerHTML');
        var contentNews = $($('div.content-section:last')[0].cloneNode(true));
        // console.log("contentNews", contentNews);
        $('#content-news-container').append(contentNews);
    }
    //Check how many content-section elements there are and skip the loop if there are 20
});
```

Comment: One approach to try might involve [counting the number of those `div`s](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5706106/1167750)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
if($('.content-section').length < 20)
```

should work.

```
var maxNewsCards = 20;

$('.show-more').click(function () {
    if($('.content-section').length < maxNewsCards ){
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            // var contentNews = $('div.content-section:last').prop('outerHTML');
            var contentNews = $($('div.content-section:last')[0].cloneNode(true));
            // console.log("contentNews", contentNews);
            $('#content-news-container').append(contentNews);
        }
    }
    //Check how many content-section elements there are and skip the loop if there are 20
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
var maxNewsCards = 20;

$('.show-more').click(function () {
  
  if ($('#content-news-container').find('.news-preview').length == maxNewsCards)
    {
      alert('Reached max limit. Display message to user or perform required action')
    return;
    }
  
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

  var contentNews = $($('div.content-section:last')[0].cloneNode(true));

    $('#content-news-container').append(contentNews);
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-section news-preview clearfix">
      <div class="title">Title of News Article</div>
          <div class="clearfix">
             <div class="image-container">
               <img src="images/news_sample208x135.jpg" width="208" height="135">
             </div>
             <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Dui luctus lectus eget libero volupat, a tempor velit malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mattis egestas lorem a sodales.</p>
             </div>
          </div>
      <a class="article-link">http://www.lintothenewsarticle.com/news/article/title-of-news-article</a>
</div><!-- /content-section -->
<br/>
<button class="show-more" type="button">Show 5 more...</button>
<br/>
<div id="content-news-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question properly, something like this should work:

```
if($('#content-news-container').children().length() < 20) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // var contentNews = $('div.content-section:last').prop('outerHTML');
        var contentNews = $($('div.content-section:last')[0].cloneNode(true));
        // console.log("contentNews", contentNews);

        $('#content-news-container').append(contentNews);
    }
}
```